# operator<< is ambiguous printing an enum value with underlying type of short

Tags: c++, enums

Quite simple. Why does this happen? It works fine will all other integer types.

```
enum : unsigned short {
    ushort_min = static_cast<unsigned short>(0u),
    ushort_max = static_cast<unsigned short>(~0u)
};

enum : short {
    short_min = short(ushort_max << (sizeof(short) * char_bit - 1)),
    short_max = short(ushort_max >> 1)
};

std::cout << short_min; // BOOM
```

Comment: Surely the error message says more than "BOOM".

Comment: Compiler tells me operator<< is ambiguous and then lists all candidate overloads (which is all the fundamental types). I thought the title was sufficient

Comment: @user1436187 - `ostream` is a type; like almost alll types, it can be used to define objects. Neither types nor objects can be overloaded. Your advice should be to overload the stream inserter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code compiles without errors with gcc. The answer here is, probably, "upgrade your compiler":

```
$ cat t.C
#include <iostream>

enum : unsigned short {
    ushort_min = static_cast<unsigned short>(0u),
    ushort_max = static_cast<unsigned short>(~0u)
};

enum : short {
    short_min = short(ushort_max << (sizeof(short) * 8 - 1)),
    short_max = short(ushort_max >> 1)
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << short_min; // BOOM
}
$ g++ -std=c++14 -c -o t.o t.C
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Ehm, I'm using the latest Clang, which I'm more inclined to trust.

Comment: How "latest" is your "latest". Mine's about a month old, as evidenced by the build timestamp.

Comment: Clang does indeed reproduce, both with libstdc++ and libc++.

Comment: g++ 5.2.1  on Ubuntu compile it but clang++ failed!